# Type parameter of imported class does not prevent instances with different type argument values from being assigned to eachother

Tags: typescript

Sorry for the vague title. I made a node module containing a little implementation of a Node style `EventEmitter`:

```
export type Events<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (...args: any[]) => any; };
export class EventEmitter<T extends Events<T>> {

  // Where listeners get stored.
  private listeners: {[K in keyof T]: T[K][]} = {} as any;

  /**
   * Registers a listeners for an event.
   */
  public on<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]) {/** ... **/}

  /**
   * Removes/deregisters an existing listener for an event.
   */
  public off<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]) {/** ... **/}


  /**
   * Raises an event, calling all listeners registered to it with the provided arguments.
   */
  public emit<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>) {/** ... **/}
}
```

Here's a little test I made inside the package

```
interface FooEvents {
    foo: (n: string) => void;
    doubleFoo: (n1: number, n2: number) => void;
}

interface BarEvents {
    foo: (n: number) => void; // notice this is different from FooEvents['foo']
    doubleFoo: (n1: number, n2: number) => void;
}

// Error. `foo` doesn't match. This is good!
// Specifically: The types of 'listeners.foo' are incompatible between these types.
const e: EventEmitter<FooEvents> = new EventEmitter<BarEvents>();
```

That's all well and good. However, I noticed that when I import this module I made into a different project and write the same test, I don't get the above error that should be there. I looked at the type definitions that are being emitted to `event-emitter.d.ts`:

```
declare class EventEmitter<T extends Events<T>> {
    private listeners;

    on<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]): void;
    off<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]): void;
    emit<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>): void;
}
```

I noticed that `listeners` does not have a type annotation, which was the only thing causing the error I wanted. I suppose this makes sense as an outside module has no reason to know of `listeners`'s existence. It looks like as long as `BarEvents` isn't missing an event name from `FooEvents`, it will compile, even if the types of the event handlers are incompatible.

A hacky way to resolve this is to add a public dummy variable inside `EventEmitter`, like: `public readonly _eventTypes: {[K in keyof T]: T[K][]} = {} as any`.

**The Question.** (edited for clarity) Is there a way to fix this without doing this (i.e. depending on `EventEmitter` having a `public`/`protected` member variable)? More specifically, I'm looking for a way to declare `on`/`off`/`emit` so that `EventEmitter`s with incompatible type args can't be assigned to each other. Edit: I want these methods to be more strongly typechecked--they should also cause compile errors ideally and not just properties.

Here's [a link to the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654). I've also included the `tsconfig` in a comment at the bottom.

Thank you much.

**!!! Edit : I recommend skipping Edit 1 and looking at Edit 2. I think I was chasing a red herring in Edit 1**

**Edit 1: more details and possible reduction of the problem**

The question is: *why are the methods of `EventEmitter<FooEvents>` and `EventEmitter<BarEvents>`  compatible with each other?* Since the signatures of each `EventEmitter` method are similar, I reduce the question to: *why is `EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on']` assignable to `EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on']` and vice versa?* I verified this is happening with the below:

```
declare let barEventsOn: EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on'];
declare let fooEventsOn: EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on'];

// No error on either of these. Both typecheck.
barEventsOn = fooEventsOn;
fooEventsOn = barEventsOn;
```

Thanks to jcalz's comment, I eventually found [#22156](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22156) and then [#18654](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)--specifically the first paragraph in the latter, where I learned constructors and methods are always checked by their parameters [bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), even with `--strictFunctionTypes`. This could be a possible explanation for the methods of `EventEmitter<FooEvents>` typechecking with the methods of `EventEmitter<BarEvents>`, which could in turn explain why these types are assignable to each other and we don't get an error above. Let's keep using the `EventEmitter.on` method as an example. In order for method parameter bivariance to be what's causing my problem here, I would think that one of the following must hold:

1. `Parameters<EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on']>` needs to be assignable to `Parameters<EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on']>` **or**
2. `Parameters<EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on']>` needs to be assignable to `Parameters<EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on']>`

It's possible that this isn't true, because I'm assuming `Parameters` discards the [index typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) information that the `EventEmitter` methods have and this isn't equivalent to what the compiler is during under the hood. **If so, stop me here.** Let's assume that we can use `Parameters` and continue by testing for the two conditions above:

```
declare let barEventsOnParams: Parameters<EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on']>;
declare let fooEventsOnParams: Parameters<EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on']>;

barEventsOnParams = fooEventsOnParams; // Test 1. Errors, good. 
     // Type '(n: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(n: number) => void'.
fooEventsOnParams = barEventsOnParams; // Test 2. No error.
     // Thus EventEmitter2<BarEvents>['on'] and EventEmitter2<FooEvents>['on'] are 
     // assignable to one another. Darn.
```

Unless I'm chasing a red herring and function parameter bivariance is not what's ultimately causing the issue here, Test 2 allows me to reduce the problem to: *Why is `fooEventsOnParams` assignable to `barEventsOnParams`*? Continuing, let's expand the types of these further:

```
declare let barEventsOnParams: ["foo" | "doubleFoo", ((n: number) => void) | ((n1: number, n2: number) => void)];
declare let fooEventsOnParams: ["foo" | "doubleFoo", ((n: string) => void) | ((n1: number, n2: number) => void)];
```

and then run some more specific tests to see why `barEventsOnParams = fooEventsOnParams` is valid:

```
// Test 1. true. This is what I think is causing the problem. I want this to be false.
type ParamMatchTest1 = (Parameters<EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on']>) extends 
    (Parameters<EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on']>) ? true : false;
// Test 2. false. Good.
type ParamMatchTest2 = (Parameters<EventEmitter<FooEvents>['on']>) extends 
    (Parameters<EventEmitter<BarEvents>['on']>) ? true : false;

// Digging deeper into Test 1. Let's compare each parameter specifically:

// Test 3. = true, which makes sense
type FirstParamMatchTest = typeof barEventsOnParams[0] extends typeof fooEventsOnParams[0] ? true : false;
// Same test, just expanding for readibility.
type FirstParamMatchExpanded = ['foo' | 'doubleFoo'] extends ['foo' | 'doubleFoo'] ? true : false;

// Test 4. = true. This is the culprit
type SecondParamMatchTest = typeof barEventsOnParams[1] extends typeof fooEventsOnParams[1] ? true : false;
type SecondParamMatchTestExpanded = ((n: number) => void) | ((n1: number, n2: number) => void) extends 
  ((n: string) => void) | ((n1: number, n2: number) => void) ? true : false;
// True. Makes sense of because of how TypeScript checks function compatibility.
// Explanation. ((n: string) => void) | ((n1: number, n2: number) => void) can handle
// either a string or a number as its first argument and the second argument is optional.
// see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions
```

So unless I made an error with my testing logic and my assumption that the compiler throws away the index typing information when comparing method types, `const e: EventEmitter<FooEvents> = new EventEmitter<BarEvents>();` typechecks because the compiler only requires the following to be true

> for each `fooKey` in `FooEvents`, there exists **some** some key `barKey` (which may or may not be equal to `fooKey`!) such that `BarEvents[barKey]` is assignable to `FooEvents[fooKey]`.

This isn't the logic I want, because the key (event name) should dictate the type of the listener. I want to use this logic

> for each `fooKey` and `value` in `FooEvents`, `BarEvents[fooKey]` must be assignable to `FooEvents[fooKey]`

Am I on the right track here? Recall that my assumption here is that the TS compiler is discarding the index typing information, which is what assigns keys (event names) to specific values `listener types` rather than just any value.

**Edit 2**

In the effort of making a simpler example of the problem (one I should have used to begin with). I found something really interesting. Removing the `emit` method  from `EventEmitter` causes typechecking errors in all the places I wanted them to! [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzgHgCoD4oF4oDeA2gNJQCWiUA1hCAPYBmUGAugFxQAUAdHwIYAnAOYpO-RCCKsAlHhwSQAbigBfAFDqAJhADGAGyHQD-FClgJkMALblgwCIMxQIADweIt5+ElSYsOATqUCFQYILkcPwOUPrkKB6OKErBoYIQ-Fr0iPogUNmcaGRuHl40dEwsWFwQlsAAcvzWEJwkADRQABYSWvqOnBiksvJQcPTkWimhUOmZ2bn5jIyFxe5IZbQMzNg1dY3NrR3dnn2CA0NyuDhjEympIQD0D1AAwvTWzcj5AK7AUMCdeKxSjQHpQADu0V0nX+nWgjkE9EE5n4YEgQgAhPcZhksjk8hBbMAVi41p5zJtKjtar59i0oO0oHweEJRJwAApCJoQBzIzBDLCXa7jSbqDTqJ6wfjQxawiAoaDAcH0f7geVdfgIOVQFDcnU82WbFGebW65r6v6VKL6b7yjoS57guwwgGgszkYSIT6oKC2VwQLRQb5gHgsTrfczg6AoTr0b76QPCA0IpHmLLgqgAIwg+no4J46kovMY0ugADF6PQfMhzEEQoxK5wuIhOIhvtZs4IhaMRVMoA36BhlU36Jx6JmAFZ6YDdm6i+uVjCddL0rhiHXACKIYSz3tiu5Fxwl3TQABCQmrPrr-cb3HXCS3O5Gc77A6Ho+4LagbY7jl3t1SN9lwgVcP3HKddBnZ893FHQTHSWIDQHGw7F5ThLxQ+xHDQCsqzqFAsBSODDAQvo-kzC8iTQixfEw3k0HPQRLwIu5kKoxw8CgCimPYwQUm4uiOPwNjUMcFIgA). The `emit` method may be the problem, but I have no idea how the inclusion of this method causes the typechecker to be happy with `on`/`off`. This may call for a new question.

Comment: Can you use `protected` instead of `private`?  The declaration emit for `private` properties is annoying this way. (see [microsoft/TypeScript#38953](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38953)).  I could write this up as an answer if it helps

Comment: I've clarified the question with an edit; and, thanks to issue link you provided, added some more information that may explain why I'm not getting the behavior I want. Using `protected` does the job, but I still want to know why the typecheck doesn't fail when it examines the types of the methods.  At this point, the question is fairly involved/complicated and I may end up making a (hopefully more clear) issue for it on the TS GitHub repo.